# Weird REDIS chars at console?

Tags: redis, ansi-escape

I have installed [*the latest version of Redis v2.8.9*](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis) from MsOpenTech

The server is up and everything is ok.

But when I invoke the `redis-cli.exe` and type in the word `info` : [*I see each  char {each click} with weird info around it*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Wn2.jpg) :

[image]

With previous version (2.8.4) of redis , it doesn't happen and all chars displayed normally.

**Question**

What are those extra chars ? and how can I make it to be displayed normally ?

*nb - windows 8 / 64bit*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug which was fixed in a newer version :

https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/issues/118

Answer (score 0):

They look like ANSI character control code used to format and colorize the display. Use an ANSI compliant terminal, or set the FAKETTY environment variable, or use the --raw option.

Comment: I'm using windows so I dont have FAKETTY  , and running --raw  (`redis-cli.exe --raw`) doesn't work. ( it does execute but still i see those weird chars)

Comment: Then you may want to try the ANSI terminals - have a look at https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon or http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/

Comment: Also note that you can probably set the FAKETTY variable also on Windows, by using "set FAKETTY=1"

Comment: ( i meant it's a valid statement but still weird chars)